# Basic math calculation

Tags: python

I am new to python and I was trying to return the value of asin(0.84). I've wrote the line as follows:

```
p1=math.cos(math.radians(lat))*math.cos(math.radians(hr_ang))*math.cos(math.radians(dec_angle))
print(math.cos(math.radians(lat)))
p2=math.sin(math.radians(lat))*math.sin(math.radians(dec_angle))
p=p1+p2
print(p)
solar_alt=math.asin(math.radians(p))
print(solar_alt)
```

The solar_alt returns a value 0.01479 instead of 57.1. If you find the asin of (0.84) on a calculator it returns 57.1 degrees where p=0.84.

If someone kindly can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `math.radians` converts an angle in degrees to radians. Is `p` an angle in degrees⸮

Comment: `math.degrees(math.asin(0.84))` is `57.14011962111089`.

Comment: P is in degrees. @kaya3 it seems that I have the statement backwords. The way you've written it is different than the way Ive written the statement.

Comment: Kaya3 thank you so much. I did have it backwords. I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `p` is not an angle at all.